# mysql join query not returning results

Tags: mysql

The below query should return 3 results but zero are being returned.  The `following` table has all the necessary rows that should join with the rows in `strings` table to produce 3 results.  Can you spot anything wrong in the query?

```
$getdash = $connectdb->prepare(
  "SELECT parent.* 
   FROM `strings` as parent 
   JOIN `following` ftable 
   ON ftable.userid=:userid
   WHERE ((ftable.sid=parent.sid AND ftable.page='1') 
    OR (ftable.sid=parent.sid AND ftable.position=parent.position AND ftable.page='0') 
    OR (ftable.profile=parent.starter)) ");

$executequery = $getdash->execute(array(":userid"=>16));

$found = $getdash->rowCount();
```

Comment: Can you post sample data and desired output?  You JOIN is a little odd -- might just need to move that to your WHERE clause.

Comment: in both tables all rows have the `userid` 16.  Each row with userid 16 also has identical `sid` and identical `position`.  1 row should at least be displayed.

Comment: Ok, understood -- so at minimum I'd recommend adding that join on the user id fields (JOIN `following` ftable on ftable.userid=following.userid) and move the (ftable.userid=:userid)  to your WHERE clause.

Comment: What's in your ftable.page field if sid and position are identical?  If you can, build a sql fiddle and we can help test the issue (http://sqlfiddle.com).